# Django Models - How to add other objects of a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

It has been difficult to find how to add in a table more them one column from other table (foreign key), see below:

Models.py:

```
class Operator(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
    operator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.operator_name


class Service(models.Model):
    operator_id = models.ForeignKey(Operator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_type = models.ForeignKey(ServiceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_descrip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name
```

Views.py

```
def myagency(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", Service.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

In the JSON response I got:

```
pk: 1
    operator_id: 1
    service_type: 3
    ...
```

I would like receive:

```
pk: 1
    operator_id: 1
    operator_name: "operator_example"
    service_type: 3
    ...
```

Summarizing: I would like to include in the table "Service" the "Primary Key" and "operator_name" objects from the table "Operator".

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Django's built-in serialization is pretty basic. You should use something like django-rest-framework which has much more powerful serializers, including the ability to include related fields.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll research about it!

Comment: Don't name the ForeignKey fields with `_id` endings, like `user_id` and `operator_id`. Django generates automatically properties with endings `_id`. In your case you'll have `operator_id` storing an object Operator and `operator_id_id` storing the actual value of the foreign key.

Comment: There is also a `JsonResponse`, which can be used instead of `HttpResponse` when the output is json.